# Marketing Cloud Connector errors: fail to find the remote site settings

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, apex-webservice, remote-site-settings

[image]

Getting this error when I select start Wizard. However, my remote site settings are there (MetaDataAPI url is in the org).
When I use to set up manually (after conducting all the additional steps) it returns a similar error:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest following every step in this trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect/install-mc-connect

Comment: @EazyE all steps have been followed, after which you come to the final step of the Start up wizard/manual set up. However, it can't find the web service call out.